# CASE GROUPING in which I need to manually add in as null to a value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one student grade of `null` that I manually need to add in the below as an `f` (to match a grade received and reported previously). I am trying to find a way to do this in SQL Server without having to do it in Excel.

Here is what I have in the select statement for the grades portion (also showing that I am doing the group by roll up at the end):

```
SELECT 
    CASE grouping (STC_GRADE) 
       WHEN 1 THEN 'total' ELSE STC_GRADE 
    END AS 'MARK ANALYSIS'....
GROUP BY ROLLUP (STC_GRADE)...
```

How would I add into that select statement that if the `STC_GRADE IS NULL` to count it as an `F` so that the results show as:

```
 '38' `F`'s
```

instead of '1' `null` and '37' `F`'s?

Comment: Is this MS or MySQL?  In MS SQL there is a ISNULL function you can call like this, ISNULL(field, 'F')   where the second paramater is the value you are replacing

Comment: I am using MS SQL.

Comment: Then you should be able to just replace STC_GRADE  with ISNULL(STC_GRADE, 'F') wherever you are using it

Comment: Brad - thanks for your help.  Do I also need to change something in the group by rollup...I now have.....SELECT case GROUPING (ISNULL(STC_GRADE,'F')) when 1 then 'total' else STC_GRADE END AS 'MARK ANALYSIS'.... group by rollup (STC_GRADE)...  or did I mess up terribly in the select again?!

Comment: In group by do the null check too

Comment: Thanks Brad.  I just couldn't get the GROUP BY ROLLUP part to work with CASE GROUPING so I eliminated the rollup and changed the case grouping to CASE WHEN .  This will get me by for now.  Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

To replace a NULL with a non-NULL value, you use this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(stc_grade, 'F') AS stc_grade
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Put some explanations in your answer.

Comment: yeah, this just got flagged for deletion so I over road that saying it just needed a little explanation.